# What does Github's 'merge into "Master"' mean?

Tags: git, github

I am a beginner user of Github, and I would like to know what the meaning of "Merge into Master" is.

Also, what does "Master" mean in this context?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It means the default branch of the remote repo on GitHub, as mentioned in "[GitHub help / Setting the default branch](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/)".

Incidentally, that convention (of naming master has the default branch) dates back from:

- [commit 3e91311 (git v0.99.2, May 2005)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e91311ae750af9bf2e3517b1e701288ac3066b9) first mention of master
- [commit cad88fd (git v0.99.2, May 2005)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cad88fdf8d1ebafb5d4d1b92eb243ff86bae740b)

It mentioned:

> ### `git-init-db`: set up the full default environment
>
> Create `.git/refs/{heads,tags}` and make `.git/HEAD` be a symlink to
>   (the as yet non-existent) `.git/refs/heads/master`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [GitHub's self-help knowledgebase](https://help.github.com/), and here is [a free guide to learning git](https://progit.org/). Either should be able to teach you what merging into "master" means.

In the future, you should try to Google your questions before posting them on Stack Overflow. This site is mostly for questions only humans can answer.

Answer (score 0):

The master branch could be thought of as the main branch, when you merge in to the main branch you are adding code from the branch you are currently in to the master branch. This web site puts it rather well...

> The "git merge" command lets you take the independent lines of development created by "git branch" and integrate them into a single branch.(https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge)

In this case the single branch is the master(or main) branch

Answer (score 0):

A branch in Git is simply a pointer to one of the commits. The name of the default branch in Git is master. The “master” in Git is exactly like any other branch. The `git init` command creates it by default and most people don’t bother to change its' name.

The best practices is to use a development (another than master) branch for commits. Once you reach a milestone, code from the development branch is merged to master. It's assumed that master branch points to the stable version of the project.